# Using dash for interactive pie chart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, plotly-dash

I want to use Dash to make an interactive pie chart like this https://plotly.com/python/pie-charts/#pie-chart-in-dash but simpler (i.e. only have one drop-down menu)
but the first hurdle is to get my data into a pandas dataframe (or a csv file to then convert into a pandas dataframe).

My data is a nested dictionary in the following format:

```
mydict={'Techstaff': {'Yes': 1}, 'Leader': {'Yes': 10, "I don't know": 1}, 'Poststaff': {"I don't know": 3, 'Yes': 8, 'No': 2}, 'Acstaff': {'Yes': 16, "I don't know": 3}, 'Reclead': {'No': 1, 'Yes': 8}, 'Engstaff': {"I don't know": 1}}
```

I think the way it would work with Dash is if it was in the following format (but not 100% sure)

```
Techstaff, Yes, 1
Leader, Yes, 10
Leader, I don't know, 1
Poststaff, I don't know, 3
Poststaff, Yes, 8
Poststaff, No, 2
Acstaff, Yes, 16
Acstaff,I don't know, 3
Reclead, No, 1
Reclead, Yes,8
Engstaff, I don't know, 1
```

I want to build this figure in Dash, so that I can have a drop down menu to allow me to chose the staff member type (e.g Poststaff) and then it would show the pie chart for that group of people, e.g. from that group of people  3 said I don't know, 8 said yes and 2 said no.

I tried a lot of things, but for a start, I am not sure how to make a nested dictionary into a table, in the format that I want (the format above). And in gereral how to make a nested dictionary into a pandas dataframe while specifying what I want as the columns and rows.

Comment: You can simply pass `mydict` to `pd.DataFrame` => `df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)`, works fine. Then you go from there: filter dataframe based on received input in a callback (Similar to the example you linked).